# Genesis page template with Powerpress

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I want to create a template that will display podcasts in a archive page with the powerpress player and links.

Powerpess talks about this on this page
http://help.blubrry.com/blubrry-powerpress/customizing-with-your-wordpress-theme/

and I have looked at the various pages taht talk about building a genesis template.

When it comes down to it, though, I don't know enough php to get this working (after trying many times)

Can someone show me how to incorporate the powerpress player and links into the template?

Comment: What does this question have to do with Genesis?

Answer (score 0):

A far easier approach would be simply [to use the category casting feature of Blubrry](http://help.blubrry.com/blubrry-powerpress/podcast-category-casting/).

But, you can also create your own page template. Combine [the instructions you linked in your question](http://help.blubrry.com/blubrry-powerpress/customizing-with-your-wordpress-theme/), with the [Codex instructions for creating a custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).

1. Create a file named `template-podpress.php`, and save it in your Theme's root directory
2. In that file, add the following:

   ```
   /**
    * Template Name: Podpress
    */
   ```
3. Add in the calls for the header and footer:

   ```
   /**
    * Template Name: Podpress
    */

   /* Header */
   get_header();

   /* Footer */
   get_footer();
   ```
4. Create a custom query to query all posts that have podcasts (outside the scope of this question, as written):

   ```
   $podcast_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   ```
5. Add the loop:

   ```
   /**
    * Template Name: Podpress
    */

   /* Header */
   get_header();

   /* Loop */
   if ( $podcast_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $podcast_query->have_posts() ) : $podcast_query->the_post();

   endwhile; endif;
   wp_reset_postdata();

   /* Footer */
   get_footer();
   ```
6. Add in the Blubrry template code, from the page you linked:

   ```
   /**
    * Template Name: Podpress
    */

   /* Header */
   get_header();

   /* Loop */
   if ( $podcast_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $podcast_query->have_posts() ) : $podcast_query->the_post();

       /* Blubrry code */
       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

       <?php the_powerpress_content(); ?>

   endwhile; endif;
   wp_reset_postdata();

   /* Footer */
   get_footer();
   ```